# El audio no funciona cuando carga la página

Tags: javascript, html, audio

El audio no me funciona, lo cree con JavaScript en lugar de ponerlo en el HTML pero debería funcionar igual. Me sale el error:

> promise state pending

Aquí dejo un ejemplo:

```js
//SONG PLAY INTRO
window.onload = function(){
  const audio = new Audio('https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3').play();
};
```

También probé con jQuery, pero tampoco me funciona:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  let audio = new Audio('../songs/intro.mp3').play();
  console.log(audio);
});
```

Comment: He puesto un mp3 que encontré online y el código funciona sin problemas. ¿Podrías añadir más detalles sobre cuándo no funciona?¿en alguna plataforma/dispositivo en concreto? ¿has comprobado con otro mp3? (quizás pueda tener que ver con el codec)

Comment: con firefox y con chrome, si probe otros... me sale Promise { <state>: "pending" }

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro tengo una duda sobre un juego de un pokemon que no consigo solucionar, son varios html y varios js y un css por lo que aqui no puedo publicarlo, como puedo hacer? Seria de gran ayuda si me dices algo =)  Un saludo